# Int to char conversion rule in C when int is outside the range of char

Tags: c

Please see the following C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c1 = 3000;
    char c2 = 250;
    printf("%d\n",c1);
    printf("%d\n",c2);
}
```

The output of the above code is

```
-72

-6
```

Please explain the integer to char conversion rule applied here as both 3000 and 250 are outside of the range of char (-128 to 127).

Comment: What do you think happens to a number, like 3000, if you attempt to store it into a value that is only 8 bits wide? Hint: examine the hexadecimal or binary representation of 3000, look at only the lower 8 bits, and determine what that value would be when considered as a 2's complement 8-bit value. If you aren't sure what 2's complement is, you can Google it.

Comment: What would you expect to happen when you overflow the size? When you stuff a 16 bit (or signed short) value into an 8-bit unsigned char, what do you think happens?

Comment: Thanks man. This helped. So to put it formally the conversion rule from int to char is as follows:
1) The int is converted to binary and then only the last 8 bits is considered.
2) Interpret the binary in 2's complement form and that will give the result.

Comment: why is it not a conversion? Suppose I put char c1 = 3000.5. Then 3000.5 is a double number and it has to be converted to the type char right? Same way why cannot we call this one as conversion from int to char ?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Exactly, this is what I thought too. And this step where they throw away the excess bits is precisely the conversion step.

Comment: Isn't it an UB?

Comment: No, @PeterJ_01, it isn't.  But it is *implementation* defined.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 It is "implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised." when `char` is signed.  Well defined when `char` is unsigned.

Comment: IMO this kind of the signed integer "conversions" should be avoided as a plaque in the sane programs

Comment: @Fawaz.A.R "The int is converted to binary and then only the last 8 bits is considered." --> not quite,  That is one possibility,  See [john](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634543/2410359)

Comment: @chux unsigned are easy:)

Comment: @chux Also it is well-defined when `char` is signed 16-bit :)

Comment: @M.M True with `char c1 = 3000;`, a 16-bit `char` is a [non-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634428/int-to-char-conversion-rule-in-c-when-int-is-outside-the-range-of-char?noredirect=1#comment88280109_50634428).  I have not seen the value of C being so portable that a `char` and `int` can have the same bit-width and `char` is unsigned.  IMO, those esoteric platforms detract from _reasonable_ portable code.

Answer (score 4):

> Please explain the integer to char conversion rule applied here as both 3000 and 250 are outside the range of char(-128 to 127).

Note first that C does not specify whether `char` is signed or unsigned.  That is left to implementations to decide, and they are not consistent on that.  On implementations where `char` is unsigned, 250 is within its range.

Supposing, however, that *your* `char`s are signed, which indeed seems consistent with your results, the C rule for the conversions implicit in the assignment statements will not satisfy you:

> the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

([C2011 6.3.1.3/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3))

Evidently no signal was raised, so the result is implementation-defined.  Among the possibilities is that the least-significant `CHAR_BIT` bits of each assigned value are stored in the target variable.

There is then an additional conversion when you call `printf()`.  The arguments are promoted from `char` to `int`, and since `int` can represent all values of type `char`, that one is value-preserving.  That allows us to conclude that it is indeed plausible that your implementation converts `int` to `char` by keeping only the least-significant bits, and interpreting them as 8-bit two's complement.

Answer (score 0):

Integer uses 4 byte and char uses 1 byte. Numbers in C are represented as signed and that means first bit from the left is for sign (positive, negative) and the rest is number in full complement. So number `3000` is represent like this `00000000000000000000000010111000` in binary and for int it is stored like this. Because char is only 1 byte last 8 bits represent saved number in char variable and that is `10111000`. When you convert this into decimal you will have -72.

Comment: `int` uses as few as 16 bits according to the standard and in some real-world implementations.  C has both signed and unsigned integer types, and it does not require negative numbers to be represented in two's complement (though in practice, two's complement is ubiquitous these days).  C does not specify how values too large for `char` to hold are converted to `char`, though the mechanism you describe is indeed very common.