# Double to char conversion rule in C when double value is outside the range of char

Tags: c

I have already asked a closely related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634428/int-to-char-conversion-rule-in-c-when-int-is-outside-the-range-of-char?noredirect=1#comment88281341_50634428) and this is an extended case of the same.

Consider the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 char c1 = 3000.5;
 printf("%d\n",c1);
}
```

The output of the above code is

```
127
```

Please explain how the double value on the right is converted to char. 
My understanding of the process is as follows:

The double value 3000.5 in floating point representation is as follows:

```
01000000 10100111 01110001 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

If we consider only the last 8 bits then the resulting binary number is

```
00000000
```

which in 2's complement representation is decimal 0. This is not consistent with the result.

If we ignore the fractional part then we get 3000 which when converted to char the result is -72, which is again not consistent with the result.

Please correct me if I have the wrong understanding of the concept.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Please explain then how this conversion is made and how we get the result as 127.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Char is signed in my system and I am using the gcc compiler on Ubuntu 14.04 OS. What possible implementation could have given this result? Kindly explain.

Comment: aside from the fact that this is undefined; floating point representations are completely irrelevant.  Conversions in C are defined in terms of values,  not representations

Comment: Floating points do not have anything to do with 2s complement. Here http://binary-system.base-conversion.ro/convert-real-numbers-from-decimal-system-to-64bit-double-precision-IEEE754-binary-floating-point.php you can see how doubles are converted to binary

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is a [real floating-integer conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Real_floating-integer_conversions), and what happens is

> The fractional part is discarded (truncated towards zero).
>
> - If the resulting value can be represented by the target type, that value is used
> - otherwise, the behavior is undefined

Since the truncated value `3000` is to large to fit in a `char` you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2):

> Double to char conversion rule in C when double value is outside the range of char

It is *undefined behavior*, if the `double` value, once it loses its fraction, it outside the `char` range.

Converting 3000.5 to a `char` resulting in -72 or 127 are examples of *undefined behavior*.  The next time code runs, the result could be [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42)) or a system crash - it is UB.

---

Conversion of a floating point like `double` consists of 2 steps

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.  C11 §6.3.1.4 1

The format of the FP and integer are irrelevant to the specified conversion.

When converting to a signed `char` in with the range -128 to 127, a `double` with the value of -128.999... to +127.999... is well defined.  Values not in that range lead to UB.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what @chux mentioned, the statement

```
char c1 = 3000.5;
```

having **undefined behavior** as `c1` is `signed` character & max limit of signed char is `127` i.e range `-128 to + 127`.

In your particular case assigning any value bigger than `SCHAR_MAX` to `c1`  gets truncated to `SCHAR_MAX(127)` itself. That means `char c1 = 127.5;` and `char c1 = 3000.5;` yields  in same output, hence the output is `127`.

Also when you are compiling your program with `-Wall` flag, it could have warn you like

> overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Werror=overflow]

So answer is there in warning itself. Suggest you to take serious note on compiler **warnings** & treat all warning as error.

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror test.c
```