# Where can I find "implementation-defined" char conversion in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm a complete beginner in C.

I tried to convert `int` 1010 to a `char` and met `error: overflow in conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ changes value from ‘1010’ to ‘-14’ [-Werror=overflow`.

Reading [Int to char conversion rule in C when int is outside the range of char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634428/int-to-char-conversion-rule-in-c-when-int-is-outside-the-range-of-char), I understood that the int to char conversion is "implementation-defined".

I was wondering where I could find the implementation detail.

I used `gcc` to compile the code, but looking at the gcc documentation, I couldn't find any code.

The closest thing I could find was this documentation

```
The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character (C90 6.1.3.4, C99 and C11 6.4.4.4).
See Implementation-defined behavior in The C Preprocessor.
```

[source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Characters-implementation.html#:%7E:text=The%20value%20of%20an,The%20C%20Preprocessor.)

But [the implementation-defined behavior page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html#Implementation-defined-behavior) doesn't seem to cover this part.

Comment: One thing you have to remember is that on some systems `char` is signed, and on other systems it's unsigned.

Comment: Your last link is to some page on “cpp”, apparently the “C preprocessor”, not to documentation on C.

Comment: Was `1010` supposed to be a binary value for newline?

Comment: Note that `1010` is an integer constant, not an integer *character* constant.  The fact that you are trying to (implicitly) convert it to type `char` has nothing to do with it.  An integer character constant would be `'a'` or `'\n'` or even `'abc'`.

Comment: sorry for the confusion: 1010 is a decimal int, not a binary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Clause 4.5 of the GCC 13.2 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html) states:

> …
> *The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an object of that type (C90 6.2.1.2, C99 and C11 6.3.1.3).*
>
> For conversion to a type of width *N*, the value is reduced modulo 2^*N* to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.
> …

So, when `char` is signed, the conversion wraps modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup> (256 for eight-bit `char`) per the above. When `char` is unsigned, the conversion wraps modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup> per C 2018 6.3.1.3 2.

Comment: My answer is substantially similar to yours. I'm trying to delete it, but running into [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392314/unable-to-delete-my-answer) again.

Comment: Thank you, I found this line too, but they said this is for "converting an integer to a signed integer type". To me, I'm "converting an integer to a char". Did I miss something?

Comment: @banhmi: `char` is an integer type. The C standard allows it to be signed or unsigned. The C implementation defines which. If it is signed, conversion from an integer to `char` is conversion to a signed integer type. If it is unsigned, conversion from an integer to `char` is conversion to an unsigned integer type.

Comment: I see thanks! I thought `char` was a smaller `string`, now I know :)

Answer (score 2):

The GCC manual has a chapter [C Implementation-Defined Behavior](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/C-Implementation.html#C-Implementation-Defined-Behavior). Within that you can go to the Integer page, and it contains

> - *The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an object of that type (C90 6.2.1.2, C99 and C11 6.3.1.3).*
>   For conversion to a type of width *N*, the value is reduced modulo *2^N* to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered the question to the letter. However, their answers are following red herrings thrown all over the place by the complete beginner, by his own admission, poster. As a result, the information that they give, although perfectly correct, is probably way above the poster's head, and in any case of very little use to him.

- First of all, that "1010" looks suspicious. It may be that it was not even intended to be in decimal.  All by coincidence, 1010b is 0ah, so it may be that the OP meant that 1010 to be in binary, and the intention was to get the carriage-return character after the conversion. Currently the C language does not officially support binary literals; it will as of the upcoming C23, and your compiler might already be supporting it, in which case it would be `int myInt = 0b1010;` but if not, then make use of the fact that 1010 in binary equals 10 in decimal.
- Secondly, if "1010" was in fact meant to be in decimal, then someone needs to explain to the poster that 1010 (decimal) will never fit inside a char, and the peculiarities and nuances of exactly how that value will be butchered by the compiler's implementation, if he nonetheless attempts to convert it, are of absolutely no use, nor consolation, to him. In order to represent 1010 (decimal) as a character, you cannot use a regular character, you need a ***wide character*** for that.

Comment: "That's how you declare a binary literal in C++ starting from version 14." This question is about C. The C language does not (as of this moment) support binary constants, though it will get added in upcoming C23.

Comment: @Lundin wh00ps, I missed that.  I will fix it.